# Is there a way to get predictive typing in an IDE on Mac? Similar To Google's Smart Compose

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I type some of the same things in code and I believe that with enough analysis, predictive typing could be applied to save me some keystrokes. Has anyone implemented this on the desktop yet?
[image: Gmail's Smart Compose]

For example. If I type `final completer = Completer();` a few times, it should say, "Hey, he's typing 'final comp' again, let's show a suggestion to complete the rest of this."

I know there are autocomplete features, but they're not analyzing your usage patterns, they're predefined.

If it matters, I'm using Intellij and VSCode sometimes.

Comment: See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7638-codota- .

Comment: @CrazyCoder that's nearly perfect! Too bad it's for Java only it seems. I wonder if it does other languages
Edit: The current version of Codota supports Java &amp; Kotlin. JavaScript support is currenlty in beta for some users, and will be released to all users soon. We will be adding other languages in the next few months.

Comment: See also https://tabnine.com/blog/deep/.

Answer (score 1):

Usually IDE's handle predictive typing on their own, but usually based on object members or variable names.  I don't think there is a solution where you want it to complete full lines of code for you, especially since one of the most important qualities of good code is its reusability.

Comment: There are solutions involving ML completion for different IDEs like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7638-codota- and https://tabnine.com/blog/deep/ .

Comment: Awesome, these would definitely be what I'm looking for. I guess it's more complex than I thought. TabNine is nearly perfect as well. Long list of supported languages, but no Dart yet :/
"
Deep TabNine supports Python, JavaScript, Java, C++, C, PHP, Go, C#, Ruby, Objective-C, Rust, Swift, TypeScript, Haskell, OCaml, Scala, Kotlin, Perl, SQL, HTML, CSS, and Bash."